# Are commitment phases open-ended?

Tags: support, area-51, commitment-phase

Once an Area 51 proposal has entered the commitment phase, is there a deadline by which it needs to achieve critical mass?

I found a couple questions lamenting about how long it takes to get enough commitments (e.g., [How should “critical mass” be calculated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53695/how-should-critical-mass-be-calculated)), so presumably it's a *long time*.

But does that mean a site could reach beta a year after entering the commitment phase? 6 months? Or are proposals intended (either manually or automatically) to be quashed after a month or two due to lack of critical mass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither the Commitment nor Definition phase has a time limit. They are both part of the proposal process: [Do proposals on Area 51 expire?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52347/do-proposals-on-area-51-expire/52400#52400)

> There is currently no plan to put a time frame on a site proposal. We want to make sure that sites have all the time they need to develop properly. That can happen very quickly for a mainstream site. It might take longer for smaller sites. Smaller sites need time to reach out to experts and develop a following.
>
> There may be some practical point where there has been absolutely no activity on a proposal and it gets deleted as a matter of system maintenance. But there's no "time limit" to get everything through in under "X" period of time.

Comment: I didn't close as a duplicate because the linked question was asking about what we now call the Definition phase.

Comment: Sweet, thanks: missed that question in my searching.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that this policy [has recently changed](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27938/changes-to-the-area-51-process-v3-0) (April 27th, 2018):

> [UNCHANGED] Proposal authors have three (3) days to complete the minimum submission requirements (5 followers, 5 example questions)
>
> A proposal has four (4) months to complete the Definition phase, and an additional four (4) months to complete Commitment
>
> Abandoned proposals exhibiting NO activity for seven (7) consecutive days are subject to closure